# Повторять ли значок процента?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: *от 50 до 70%* или *от 50% до 70%?*

С другими единицами понятно, что только в конце обычно их пишут, но с процентами случай особый, ведь они пишутся даже без пробела.

Также понятно, что в устной речи и в случае процентов называешь их только в конце, но, может, устная речь в данном случае отличается от написанного?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...с процентами случай особый, ведь они пишутся даже без пробела.

Почему без пробела? **[С пробелом:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=268474)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

.

> Как правильно: от 50 до 70% или от 50% до 70%?

Правильно так ([**из справочника Мильчина**](http://diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/6.html#6.4.2.)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего себе, спасибо! А я думал без!

Comment: В цифровой типографике говорить о машинном кернинге не приходится, а о ручном — только для текстов, где знак % не встречается. Общее правило для экранного набора: лишних пробелов не должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что речь является «руководящей и направляющей» по отношению к письму. Но не надо думать, что написанное или напечатанное читать не будут, да к тому же, в рост с прописными громоздкие %% делают строчку (на вид) глаголической шифровкой. Правильно будет педантично проставлять все знаки только в специальных книжках и учебниках.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и думал.